# Is there a way to set ro.kernel.qemu to 0 in a emulator?

Tags: android-emulator

I replaced a modified build.prop which contains ro.kernel.qemu=0 to the system.img with yaffey, but it did not work. When the emulator restarted, ro.kernel.qemu=1 still exists in the output of adb shell getprop.

**EDIT:**

I also tried:

1. add `ro.kernel.qemu=0` in default.prop in ramdisk.img
2. add `setprop ro.kernel.qemu 0` in init.goldfish.rc in ramdisk.img

But all these did not work. When I start the emulator with modified ramdisk.img, `ro.kernel.qemu` is still 1 in the output of `adb shell getprop`.

I am now trying to rebuild the kernel to set it to 0, but I did not find where `ro.kernel.qemu` is set in the kernel source code.

Appreciated for any advices.